# Unable to upload code to the Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, avr, avrdude, flash

I tried to to upload a hex file I generated for the Arduino Nano using avrdude but I keep getting the error:

```
avrdude: stk500_2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
```

First the arduino board stops doing whatever it is programmed to do, in this case powering a vibration motor .
Then this error keeps showing up in delays of around 10 seconds.
That error is then followed by

```
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application re
quest.
```

which appears to be caused by me pulling out the USB cable after waiting a while.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you disconnect the motor while you are uploading. The power it is using, or the electrical noise it is generating, may intefere with the uploading process.

Comment: thanks for your help, I was just able to upload the hex using Xloader software.